# Encrypted Email and Mailing Lists

Tags: email, gpg

My organization uses PGP-encrypted email, but are unable to use it
with our mailing list because we send emails to the mailing list
address, and not to the addresses on our member's individual PGP keys.

I was told by one of my colleagues that Thunderbird's Enigmail plugin
had an option to "Edit per-recipient rules." Using this, they were
able to send encrypted emails to me and other members encrypted with
their own PGP keys.

I'm using Notmuch as an email frontend on Emacs and smtpmail to send
it. I haven't been able to find any similar options on here[^1](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/message.html),
here[^2](https://notmuchmail.org/emacstips/) and here[^3](https://notmuch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: If you know the key ids for all the recipients on the list, does adding them to `mml-secure-openpgp-encrypt-to-self` help (I can't remember offhand if notmuch goes via message/mml)?

Comment: I have all of them, and I've recommended that we just use ad-hoc email threads and just reply-to-all, but there are still those who prefer the mailing list format.

Comment: The point of using `mml-secure-openpgp-encrypt-to-self` is that all those keys will be used  to encrypt the message, regardless of the recipients, so that if you send just to the list address, all the people receving the message should be able to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through `man gpg`, I was able to find the `--group` option, which allowed me to include the following in my `$HOME/.gnupg/gpg.conf` file:

```
group ${mailing list email} = 12345 12345 12345...
```

Writing an email after doing `M-x mml-secure-message-sign-encrypt` and sending it normally, it was encrypted to the key-id's I specified in the group!

Answer (score 0):

> My organization uses PGP-encrypted email, but are unable to use it with our mailing list because we send emails to the mailing list address, and not to the addresses on our member's individual PGP keys.

Check out https://schleuder.org "an OpenPGP-enabled mailing list manager with resending capabilities".

> I was told by one of my colleagues that Thunderbird's Enigmail plugin

In the newest release Enigmail is no longer supported but there's now builtin openpgp support.

Comment: The person in question is holding off of upgrading Thunderbird because of Enigmail feature.

Comment: And I'm aware of schleuder, but it's not something we can set up right this moment.